# Android - App crashes immediately after launch (DevEnvironment: Eclipse, Emulator: BlueStacks, API: 17)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using eclipse for developing a game for android. The game is pretty much finished but it won't launch correctly on my emulator of choice (BlueStacks).
It only shows a white screen and the infobar for about 0.5 seconds before crashing. App is still open in background after crashing but can't do or display anything.

I can compile and install the application and the syntax is correct... I assume that my mistake is somewhere in the manifest.

here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.ralfkraemer.starsandstrikes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="de.ralfkraemer.starsandstrikes.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The following is my main activity class

```
package de.ralfkraemer.starsandstrikes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import de.ralfkraemer.starsandstrikes.R;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymainmenu);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        randomizeFact();

    }

    // RANDOM FACT
    String[] factresource = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.factres);
    protected void randomizeFact(){

        TextView randomFact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1); 
        Random random = new Random();

        int maxIndex = factresource.length;
        int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);

        randomFact.setText(factresource[generatedIndex]);

    }

    // START GAME
    public void startGame(){

        Game currentGame = new Game();
        currentGame.setScore(0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitygame);
        currentGame.running = true;
    }

    // PLAY STORE (RATE)
    public void openPlayStore(){

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("url");
        Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void goToAbout(){

        setContentView(R.layout.activityabout);

    }

    public void goToHowToPlay(){

        setContentView(R.layout.activityhowtoplay);

    }

    public void goToHighscores() throws IOException{

        Highscores highscores = new Highscores();
        setContentView(R.layout.activityhighscores);
    }
}
```

And here is the main activity xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="${linearPackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:contentDescription="@string/header_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_mainmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
        android:text="@string/mm_button_play"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:onClick="startGame"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="@string/mm_randomfact_placeholder"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_randomfact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
        android:text="@string/mm_button_randomfact"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:onClick="randomizeFact"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_highscores"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
                android:text="@string/mm_button_highscores"
                style="android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/button_default"
                android:onClick="goToHighscores" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_howtoplay"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
                android:text="@string/mm_button_howtoplay"
                style="android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/button_default"
                android:onClick="goToHowToPlay" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_about"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
                android:text="@string/mm_button_about"
                style="android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/button_default"
                android:onClick="goToAbout" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_rate"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
                android:text="@string/mm_button_rate"
                style="android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/button_default"
                android:onClick="openPlayStore" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I posted one problem - likely the cause of your crash. you should really post a log or stacktrace when you have a crash

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getResources` while the activity is instantiating on this line here:

```
// RANDOM FACT
String[] factresource = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.factres);
```

and the implied `Activity.this` object does not have a valid context, so it crashes. You need to call this in `onCreate` or in another method that is called after the object instantiates.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer :) getResources() is now called in the method "randomizeFact()". this is definitely an improvement but the app still crashes. do you know how i can get a stacktrace or error log of bluestacks?